# Kernel dies in Jupyter Notebook after upgrading Ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.04

Tags: python, jupyter

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.04. The kernel dies when I start Jupyter notebook.

Note: I did not install Jupyter notebook using Conda. Thanks

Comment: Have you updated the jupyter? might be helpful!

Comment: You're welcome, I turned my comment to answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update your jupyter, it should work.

e.g: if you installed it using pip run something like:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter --user
```

or

```
sudo pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve this problem which has the additional advantage of being automatically updated by the Software Updater because Jupyter Notebook is in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 17.04. Run the below commands.

In Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo pip uninstall jupyter
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

In Ubuntu 18.04-19.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter # python-ipykernel is dropped from the default Ubuntu repos
```

python-ipykernel is necessary for running Python 2.x programs in Jupyter Notebook, which otherwise supports only Python 3.x.

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the following worked for me

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip3 install jupyter
```

Even though I installed 17.04 from scratch and had previously installed jupyter the same way then.

FWIW
Python 3.5.3
IPython 6.0.0
jupyter 4.3.0
Google Chrome 58.0.3029.81